fittedBox inside stack widget not working
i want to show camera preview on screen and i have set height and width in sizedBox widget, the problem in video is streched to fit, instead it should be fit like boxfit.cover, i tried wrapping my CameraPreview widget inside FittedBox widget but i am getting error, what should i do to make it not strech but fit to that dimensions. (i can allow little zoom).
return Stack(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: mQWidth,
                      height: mQHeight / 1.3,
                      child: FittedBox(child: CameraPreview(cameraController)),
                    ),

error i am getting is
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFittedBox#5d99b
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2165 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was:

Help is appriciated. TiA.

how do you expect it to fit to double.infinity? Give it an actual width

tried this also, but problem is still same.
